# Limiting TCP Socket clients connection

Tags: c, tcp

This program is a tcp server and I only want 2 clients to connect at all times.
I have a counter that keeps track of client connections, `count`, but I want to use it to block any other connections if there are 2 clients already connected. I've tried multiple times, but it seems that it does not have any effect.
Momentarily, the `count` is situated before making a thread to handle the client, in the `if` statement, but it won't refuse connection if I have a third client connected.
What should I actually do?

```
 for( ; ; )
  {
    int client;
    thData *td; //parameter executed by thread
    int length = sizeof(from);

    printf("[SERVER] Waiting at port : %d\n", PORT);
    fflush(stdout);
    //accept client
    if((client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length)) < 0 )
    {
      perror ("[SERVER]Error at accept\n");
      continue;
    }

    count ++;

    printf("Count : %d\n", count);
    //connection established
    int idThread; //thread id
    int cl;

    td = (struct thData*)malloc(sizeof(struct thData));
    td -> idThread = i++;
    td -> cl = client;

    if (count < 3)
      pthread_create (&th[i], NULL, &treat, td);
    else 
      close((int)td);

    printf("Client descr : %d\n", client);
  } //for
```

Comment: `close((int)td);` doesn't seem right at all

Comment: Yeah, thats why I dont know how to do close the client.

Comment: what about close(client);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I think your code, that closes connection, must be something like this:

```
if (count < 3)
    pthread_create (&th[i], NULL, &treat, td);
else {
    shutdown( client, SHUT_RDWR );
    close( client );
}
```

From [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html):
`shutdown` - The  shutdown() call causes all or part of a full-duplex connection on the socket associated with sockfd to be shut down.  If how is SHUT_RD, further receptions will be disallowed.  If how is SHUT_WR, further transmissions will be disallowed.  If how is SHUT_RDWR, further receptions and transmissions will be disallowed.

2) you can write something along those lines ( just an alternative, it's a bit ugly - `sleep` involved ):

```
printf("[SERVER] Waiting at port : %d\n", PORT);
fflush(stdout);
int length = sizeof(from);  
for( ; ; ) {
    int client;
    thData *td; //parameter executed by thread
    while ( count < 3 ) {
        if((client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length)) < 0 ) {
            perror ("[SERVER]Error at accept\n");
            continue;
        }
        count++;
        printf("Count : %d\n", count);
        //connection established
        int idThread; //thread id
        int cl;
        td = (struct thData*)malloc(sizeof(struct thData));
        td -> idThread = i++;
        td -> cl = client;
        pthread_create (&th[i], NULL, &treat, td);
        printf("Client descr : %d\n", client);
    }
    sleep(??);
}
```